# This 64-bit process failed to load the library R.dll. Native error message is 'The operation completed successfully'

Tags: .net, .net-standard, r.net, anycpu

I have a .net program that is built on .net framework 4.7.2, which call upon the rdotnet DLL (which is built on .net standard 2.0) to run R script, both the program and the DLL are compiled for the 'Any CPU' platform, when I deploy it to a 64-bit windows 10 machine and execute the program, it keeps saying the following:

```
This 64-bit process failed to load the library R.dll. Native error message is 'The operation completed successfully'
```

I don't get this message when I run the program in debug mode though. My question is that is my setup above correct or should I compile these in different framework/platform combination?

Comment: Hello, have you ever found the answer to this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @for-comment, have you ever found the answer to this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, have you ever found the answer to this error? :) Thanks